# SQL Query with recursive foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, recursive-query

I have a table with columns EmployeeID, EmployeeName, and ManagerID. ManagerID is a recursive FK of EmployeeID. I am trying to query the table so that the name of employees who are managers are provided. My train of thought is that an Employee would be a Manager if their EmployeeID is also a ManagerID. I set the ManagerID to be NOT NULL because that person would be the manager's manager. When I execute the query a blank manager column is returned.

```
SELECT EmployeeName AS Manager
FROM Employee E
WHERE E.EmployeeID=E.ManagerID AND
E.ManagerID <> null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EmployeeName AS Manager
FROM Employee 
WHERE EmployeeID IN 
      ( SELECT ManagerID 
        FROM Employee
        WHERE ManagerID IS NOT NULL
      )
  AND ManagerID IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
SELECT EmployeeName AS Manager                --- show name 
FROM Employee M                               --- of any employee
WHERE EXISTS                                  --- for whom exists
      ( SELECT *                              --- at least one
        FROM Employee E                       --- employee
        WHERE M.EmployeeID = E.ManagerID      --- that is under his management
      )
  AND ManagerID IS NOT NULL                   --- and is not the "root" manager
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a question that builds off of this. If I wanted only the names of people who do not have managers, why does inserting "<>" instead of "=" not work? Shouldn't putting not equal equate to the opposite of the query above? Thanks again.

Comment: Finding all who do not have managers would be easier actually, just use: `SELECT EmployeeName FROM Employee WHERE ManagerID IS NULL`. No need for subqueries.

Comment: Oops, I had a typo there, I meant the employees who are NOT managers i.e. the people being managed by the first-line managers that result from the query above.

Comment: That depends on how many levels of managers you have and which levels you want included. Example, if `A` is the only boss ("root" manager, no-one above) and `A` manages `B` and `C`, `B` manages `D` and `E`, `E` manages `G`. Which ones would you want returned?  Only `B` and `C` (managed by A)?  Or `C`, `D` and `G` (those that manage no-one?)

Comment: I have two levels of managers `A` is the root manager and `B` and `C` are managed by `A`. I am trying to find out the names of those that are managed by `B` and `C` i.e. those that manage no-one.

Comment: You could simply change the `EXISTS` to `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question (it will return middle managers too - see comment in other answer that states only first level managers are wanted), but nm.

Comment: @Bohemian: You are right but read OP's comments here. He actually has one "boss", then another level of managers, then non-managers. If he had mutiple manager levels, you are right, it would be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed from a comment that you only want employees that are first-line managers. Therefore, you can do a further join to assert that there are no *further* sub-employees:

```
SELECT distinct M.*
FROM Employee m
join Employee e on e.managerid = m.employeeid
left join Employee s on s.managerid = e.employeeid
WHERE s.employeeid is null;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH allfkey AS
(

    SELECT referenced_object_id,object_name(referenced_object_id) [object_name],name
    from sys.foreign_keys where parent_object_id=object_id('employee') -- put your table name here

    UNION ALL

   SELECT f.referenced_object_id,object_name(f.referenced_object_id) [object_name],f.name
    from sys.foreign_keys f join allfkey on f.parent_object_id=allfkey.referenced_object_id

)
SELECT * from allfkey
```